# How to change Xcode project entirely?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos, ipad

I have an xcode project boilerplate codebase that I am using for my third project.

It has class prefixes from the last project and also the name of the previous project everywhere. plist, pch, project name, schemes, build targets, folders etc.

Also the copyright text in the classes need to be changed to the new one for the new client.

Is there a consolidated way to change all the identity from my previous project to the new one rather than doing it one by one?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Xcode's refactoring tools to rename classes and other identifiers wherever they occur, but you still have to do each identifier individually -- you can't change all the classes at the same time. Find and replace should take care of things like copyright text.

The Edit->Refactor->Rename... command (or control-click on a name to get to the Refactor context menu) is the best way to rename things like classes and variables because it will catch cases you might not have thought of. For example, renaming a class will change the name in storyboard and .xib files.